# d3.js coords while adding elements

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

Can anyone explain me on how `d3.js places` the `svg-element` in dom. Below is the code and fiddle.

The below code should add a text element to dom with x and y axis as indicated.

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <text x="0" y="25">Hello Shane</text>
</svg>
```

The below code should do the same, just in JS way.

```
d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 100).attr("height",100).append("text").text("Hello Shane").attr("x", 0).attr("y", 25).style("fill", "blue");
```

Why is the two texts `not overlapping here?`
http://jsfiddle.net/8gcsxbay/1/

I am placing one using normal HTML tags and other using `d3/js` way. Both the coords are same, yet they are in showing different `coords`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3.js places it in the same place as HTML version. The two  elements are placed next to each other by default. See your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gcsxbay/2/)

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <text x="0" y="25">Hello Shane</text>
</svg>
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <text x="0" y="25">Hello Shane</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Also, if you do want the svg elements to overlap, you could nest both in another svg, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/dnhemL2w/ and then control the position of each with `x` and `y` attributes. For more see http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-element.html

Answer (score 1):

Or if you're looking to add the blue text to your existing SVG, use

```
d3.select("svg").append("text")…
```

which selects the first existing SVG element and puts an additional text element inside if.